# How to refractor a class which can have two flows

Tags: java

I have a class like below.

```
public class Fig implements SomeThing {

    private BiPredicate<List<A>, B> predicate;
    private BiPredicate<Set<X>, Y> otherpredicate;

    private SomeThing something;
    private SomeThing somethingElse;

    public Fig(BiPredicate<List<A>, B> p, SomeThing something, SomeThing somethingElse) {
        this.predicate = p;
        this.something = something;
        this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
    }
    public Fig(BiPredicate<Set<X>, Y> p, SomeThing something, SomeThing somethingElse) {
        this.otherpredicate = p;
        this.something = something;
        this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
    }
    @Override
    public List<String> apply(List<A> a, B b) {
        if (predicate.test(a, b))
            return something.call(a, b);
        else 
            return somethingElse.call(a, b);
    }
    @Override
    public List<String> applyAnother(Set<X> a, Y b) {
        if (otherpredicate.test(a, b))
            return something.call(a, b);
        else
            return somethingElse.call(a, b);
    }
}
```

It seems one of the predicate would have null value. And it doesn't seem correct me.

In other places I would create concrete instance of Fig and call the apply methods depending on the parameters. How to refractor this sort of code?

None of the alphabets are generic and are just representation for concrete classes.

Answer (score 1):

You only set one predicate by your constructors in each case, the other is not set.

You have to set both predicates within each constructor because you will use only one constructor to create your instance.

It is not a problem of java but of your implementation. I would  use Collection (extended by List and  Set) or create two Classes.

```
public class Fig implements SomeThing {

    private BiPredicate<Collection<A>, B> predicate;

    private SomeThing something;
    private SomeThing somethingElse;

    public Fig(BiPredicate<Collection<A>, B> p, SomeThing something, SomeThing somethingElse) {
        this.predicate = p;
        this.something = something;
        this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
   }

   @Override
   public Collection<String> apply(Collection<A> a, B b) {
       if (predicate.test(a, b))
           return something.call(a, b);
      else 
          return somethingElse.call(a, b);
   }
```

}

Or

```
public class FigList implements SomeThing {

    private BiPredicate<List<A>, B> predicate;

    private SomeThing something;
    private SomeThing somethingElse;

    public Fig(BiPredicate<List<A>, B> p, SomeThing something, SomeThing somethingElse) {
        this.predicate = p;
        this.something = something;
        this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> apply(List<A> a, B b) {
        if (predicate.test(a, b))
            return something.call(a, b);
        else 
           return somethingElse.call(a, b);
   }
```

}

```
public class FigSet implements SomeThing {
  
    private BiPredicate<Set<A>, B> predicate;

    private SomeThing something;
    private SomeThing somethingElse;

    public Fig(BiPredicate<Set<A>, B> p, SomeThing something, SomeThing somethingElse) {
        this.predicate = p;
        this.something = something;
        this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> apply(Set<A> a, B b) {
        if (predicate.test(a, b))
            return something.call(a, b);
        else 
           return somethingElse.call(a, b);
   }
}
```

ADDED
Using both predicates within same class

```
public class Fig implements SomeThing {

    private BiPredicate<List<A>, B> predicate;
    private BiPredicate<Set<X>, Y> otherpredicate;

    private SomeThing something;
    private SomeThing somethingElse;

    public Fig(BiPredicate<List<A>, B> p1, BiPredicate<Set<X>, Y> p2, SomeThing something, SomeThing somethingElse) {
        predicate = p1;
        otherpredicate = p2;
        this.something = something;
        this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> apply(List<A> a, B b) {
        if (predicate.test(a, b)) {
            return something.call(a, b);
        } else {
            return somethingElse.call(a, b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> applyAnother(Set<X> a, Y b) {
        if (otherpredicate.test(a, b)) {
            return something.call(a, b);
        } else {
            return somethingElse.call(a, b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> call(List<A> pA, B pB) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> call(Set<X> pA, Y pB) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to override the second method too. Since something is an interface.

Comment: then you have to use only one constructor with both predicates

Comment: You are using Composite pattern here by using SomeThing within Something (Fig). Your Class Fig is missing call Method you are using in the Code e.g `return something.call(a, b);` I added the call Method for Fig in me added Code

Comment: your SomeThing interface is alittle bit weird . You should do some edit on it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the arguments of type `Something` are related to each other. So it would be nice to pack them together:

```java
class SomeThings {
    private SomeThing something;
    private SomeThing somethingElse;

    public SomeThings(SomeThing someThing, SomeThing someThingElse) {
        this.something = someThing;
        this.somethingElse = someThingElse;
    }

    public SomeThing get() {
        return something;
    }

    public SomeThing getElse() {
        return somethingElse;
    }
}
```

If you want to use one class (if you use many containers like List, Stack, Map and don't want to write a class for each one) you could use generics:

```java
class Fig1<S, T extends Collection<? extends Object>> implements SomeThing {

    private BiPredicate<T, S> predicate;
    private SomeThings somethings;

    public Fig1(BiPredicate<T, S> p, SomeThings someThings) {
        this.predicate = p;
        this.somethings = someThings;
    }

    public void setPredicate(BiPredicate<T, S> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    public BiPredicate<T, S> getPredicate() {
        return predicate;
    }

    public SomeThings getSomethings() {
        return somethings;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> apply(T a, S b) {
        if (getPredicate().test(a, b))
            return somethings.get().call(a, b);
        else
             return somethings.getElse().call(a, b);
    }
 }
```

Usage:

```java
SomeThings someThings  = new SomeThings(new SomeThing(), new SomeThing());

BiPredicate<List<String>, Integer> p1 = (strings, integer) -> false;
BiPredicate<Stack<String>, Integer> p2 = (strings, integer) -> false;

Fig1<Integer, List<String>> fList = new Fig1<>(p1, someThings);
Fig1<Integer, Stack<String>> fStack = new Fig1<>(p2, someThings);
```

However, if you want to use only two containers just write two classes like @Michael Katt described. It's cleaner.